# CSS positioning in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, position, alignment

I've been unable to fix the IE 7 and 8 compatibility issues I am having with my CSS code.

The site is [here](http://www.grandten.com/home.php).

In IE, the header is gone, the shadow boxes that are supposed to highlight the text (in the individual pages) are gone, spacing is horrible, the footer is misaligned, etc.

I experimented with `z-index` and `position`, but I just don't have the coding chops to fix this.

**CSS**

```
/**AGE VERIFICATION / SPLASH PAGE----
    -------------------------------------------------------------*/
#Splash {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
#SplashHolder {
    width: 650px;
    height: 280px;
    margin: 8% auto 0 auto;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    padding: 15px;
    border: 3px double rgba(102,102,102,.5);
}
#SplashLogo {
    width: 182px;
    height: 73px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(../images/Logo_Splash.png) no-repeat;
}
#SplashBody h1, #SplashBody h2 {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#SplashBody h2, .SplashAge li a {
    font-size: 16px
}
.SplashAge li a, #SplashHolder {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2)
}
.left {
    float: left
}
.right {
    float: right
}
.SplashAge li {
    width: 300px;
    display: inline;
}
.SplashAge li a {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(206,55,34,.1);
    padding: 8px 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    border: 3px double rgba(206,55,34,.5);
}
.SplashAge li a:hover {
    background: rgba(206,55,34,.5)
}
#SplashInfoBottom {
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#SplashInfoBottom ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 15px 0 0;
}
#SplashInfoBottom ul li h2 {
    font-size: 12px
}
#EventSplash {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
#EventSplashHolder {
    width: 750px;
    height: 460px;
    margin: 8% auto 0 auto;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    padding: 15px;
    border: 3px double rgba(102,102,102,.5);
}
#EventSplashLogo {
    width: 182px;
    height: 73px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(../images/Logo_Splash.png) no-repeat;
}
#EventSplashBody h1, #EventSplashBody h2 {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#EventSplashBody h2, .SplashAge li a {
    font-size: 16px
}
.EventSplashAge li a, #EventSplashHolder {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2)
}
.left {
    float: left
}
.right {
    float: right
}
.EventSplashAge li {
    width: 350px;
    display: inline;
}
.EventSplashAge li a {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(206,55,34,.1);
    padding: 8px 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    border: 3px double rgba(206,55,34,.5);
}
.EventSplashAge li a:hover {
    background: rgba(206,55,34,.5)
}
#EventSplashInfoBottom {
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#EventSplashInfoBottom ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 15px 0 0;
}
#EventSplashInfoBottom ul li h2 {
    font-size: 12px
}
/*--HEADER, NAV AND SUB NAV-
    ----------------------------------------------------------*/
.main {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#EnjoyResponsibly {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
#NavBack {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background: rgba(35, 31, 32, .8);
    height: 55px;
    border-bottom: 9px solid #231f20;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 800;
}
#NavBackBlue {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 56px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #221b5e;
    : ;
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 800;
}
.nav_container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    text-align: left;
}
.navWrap {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 0px 3px 3px 3px;
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 600px;
    height: 56px;
    background: none;
}
.nav {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 57px;
}
a#logo {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 140px;
    height: 47px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    outline: none;
    margin: 6px 23px 9px 11px;
    background: url("../images/GTD_Logo.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.nav li {
    float: left
}
.nav ul .MainNavigation {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav a {
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: .1em;
}
.nav a.navTrigger {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0 7px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.nav a.navTrigger span {
    padding: 23px 1px 23px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav a.Inner span {
    width: 180px
}
.nav a.Products span {
    width: 100px
}
.nav a.connect span {
    width: 100px
}
.nav a.event span {
    width: 135px
}
.nav a.open span, .nav a.active span {
    color: #fff;
    top: 1px;
    padding: 22px 1px 24px 1px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #ccc;
}
.nav .subnav ul, .navWrap {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    border-top: 0;
}
.navWrap {
    border: 1px dotted #221b5e;
    border-top: 0;
}
.nav .subnav ul, .nav {
    border: 1px dotted #231f20;
    border-top: 0;
}
.nav .subnav {
    position: relative
}
.nav .subnav ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 57px;
    left: 1px;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 159px;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 0;
}
.navWrap, .nav .subnav ul {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #000
}
.nav .subnav ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 18px;
}
.nav .subnav ul li:first-child {
    padding-top: 12px
}
.nav .subnav ul li:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 12px
}
.nav ul li:hover .subnav ul li a {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
.nav .subnav ul li a {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.nav .subnav ul li:hover {
    color: #000
}
.nav .subnav ul li:first-child:hover {
    background: url("/assets/global/nav_indent.png") -5px 13px no-repeat
}
.nav .subnav ul li:hover a {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    background: 0;
}
#AboutDD ul {
    width: 235px
}
#MakesDD ul {
    width: 570px;
    left: -292px;
    height: 320px;
}
#MakesDD ul li {
    width: 140px;
    margin: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
#MakesDD ul li#middle {
    margin: 24px 0 0 195px
}
#MakesDD ul li#Last {
    margin: 24px 0 0 385px
}
#MakesDD ul li#BL {
    margin: 184px 0 0 5px
}
#MakesDD ul li#BC {
    margin: 184px 0 0 195px
}
#MakesDD ul li#BR {
    margin: 184px 0 0 385px
}
#MakesDD ul li a img {
    opacity: .6
}
#MakesDD ul li a img:hover {
    opacity: 1
}
#MakesDD ul li a span {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #ccc;
}
.subnav ul li h3, .subnav ul li span {
    color: #fff
}
.subnav ul li h3 {
    font-size: 18px
}
#MakesDD ul li a span.bottle {
    float: left;
    width: 55px;
    height: 90px;
}
#ConnectDD ul {
    width: 200px;
    left: -22px;
}
#ConnectDD ul li {
    width: 180px
}
#ConnectDD ul li.Distributor {
    height: 80px
}
#EventsDD ul {
    width: 600px;
    left: -400px;
    height: 400px;
}
#EventsDD ul li {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}
#EventsDD ul li a img {
    opacity: .6
}
#EventsDD ul li a img:hover {
    opacity: 1
}
#EventsDD ul li a span {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #ccc;
}
.subnav ul li h3, .subnav ul li span {
    color: #fff
}
.subnav ul li h3 {
    font-size: 18px
}
#EventsDD ul li.ImagDrop {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
}
#EventsDD ul li.ImagDrop {
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: absolute;
}
#EventsDD ul li#BMC {
    margin: 24px 0 0 5px
}
.Menu_DD_Events {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    background: rgba(24, 24, 24, .7);
    padding: 0;
    margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
}
.DDHeading {
    margin-top: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 6px 8px;
}
#MakesDD ul li.ImagDrop {
    width: 140px;
    height: 114px;
}
.DDHeading {
    margin-top: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 6px 8px;
}
.Menu_DD_Bottles {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    background: rgba(24, 24, 24, .7);
    padding: 0;
    margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
}
#MakesDD ul li.ImagDrop {
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: absolute;
}
.social {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    height: 57px;
    border-left: 1px solid #181818;
    width: 24px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
.social a.twit, .social a.fb {
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("../images/social-icons-sprite.png");
}
.social a.twit {
    height: 17px;
    background-position: 2px 0;
    margin: 9px 0 8px 4px;
}
.social a.twit:hover {
    background-position: -19px 0
}
.social a.fb {
    height: 21px;
    background-position: 2px -23px;
    margin: 0 0 0 4px;
}
.social a.fb:hover {
    background-position: -19px -23px
}
.contentWrap {
    width: 700px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.contentWrapMed {
    width: 900px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.contentWrapBig {
    width: 1000px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.facebook_tab .contentWrap {
    width: 492px;
    background: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.content {
    width: 700px;
    padding: 110px 0 0 50px;
    background: url("images/BottlesBack.png") top right;
    min-height: 700px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #000;
}
.contentMed {
    width: 900px;
    padding: 110px 0 0 50px;
    background: url("images/BottlesBack.png") top right;
    min-height: 700px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #000;
}
.contentBig {
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 110px 0 0 50px;
    background: url("images/BottlesBack.png") top right;
    min-height: 700px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #000;
}
.contentBloody {
    width: 900px;
    padding: 50px 0 0 50px;
    background: url("images/BloodyTexture.png") top right;
    min-height: 700px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #000;
}
.facebook_tab .content {
    width: 492px;
    background: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.content h1 {
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #704a3c;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    max-width: 575px;
    clear: both;
}
.facebook_tab .content h1 {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 492px;
    height: 254px;
    background: url("/assets/facebook_tab/main_heading.png");
}
.content h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #2c2c2c;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    max-width: 575px;
}
.content h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #704a3c;
    line-height: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    max-width: 575px;
}
.content p {
    max-width: 575px
}
.contentBloody h1 {
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #704a3c;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    max-width: 575px;
    clear: both;
}
.contentBloody h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #2c2c2c;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    max-width: 575px;
}
.contentBloody h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #704a3c;
    line-height: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    max-width: 575px;
}
.contentBloody p {
    max-width: 575px
}
/*--PAGES----------------------------------------------------*/
.BottlePhoto {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
.BottlePhotoBig {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
    height: 700px;
    margin: 0 100px 0 0;
}
.BottlePhotoMap {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
.BloodyEvent {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 550px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 100px 0 0;
}
#WireWorks {
    background: url(../images/Wireworks_Side.jpg) top center
}
#Firepuncher {
    background: url(../images/firetext.jpg) top center no-repeat
}
#MedfordRumBack {
    background: url(../images/barrel1.jpg) center no-repeat
}
#SpecialReserveBack {
    background: url(../images/SpecialReserve_Side.jpg) top center no-repeat
}
#Amandine {
    background: url(../images/amandine_side.jpg) top center
}
#Craneberry {
    background: url(../images/craneberry_side.jpg) top center
}
#Angelica {
    background: url(../images/angelica_Side.jpg) top center
}
#AboutPage {
    background: url(../images/About_Side.jpg) top center
}
#CraftPage {
    background: url(../images/Craft_Side.jpg) top center
}
#LibationPage {
    background: url(../images/Libation_Side.jpg) top center
}
#TheCraftBack {
    background: url(../images/Background_Tub.jpg) center
}
#ContentPageBack {
    background: url(../images/BottleBack.png) rgba(255,255,255,.9);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#ContentPageBackBloody {
    background: url(../images/BloodyTexture.png) rgba(255,255,255,.9);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
/*--TABLES--------------------------------------------------------*/
/*-FOOTER-----------------------------------------------------------*/
#ft_wrapper {
    height: 15px;
    clear: both;
}
#footer_top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.touch #footer_top {
    position: relative
}
.non_sticky #footer_top {
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
}
.anchorTab {
    position: absolute;
    top: -60px;
    right: 30px;
}
.anchorTab a {
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 324px;
    height: 144px;
    background: url(../images/Toggle.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.anchorTab a.open {
    background-position: 0 -200px
}
.footer {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../images/Menu_Back.jpg) repeat;
}
.FooterPattern {
    height: 81px;
    width: 100%;
}
.FooterPattern ul {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px 0 0 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
.FooterPattern ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 30px 25px 0 0;
}
.FooterPattern ul li a {
    color: #f0f0f0
}
.FooterPattern ul li a:hover {
    color: #be6045
}
#FooterContent {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 500px;
    width: 950px;
    margin-top: 55px;
}
#FooterHolder {
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#FeaturesHolder {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
}
#AnthemSobo {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    font-size: 9px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#AnthemSobo a {
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#FooterTop {
    background: url(../images/FooterTopBottom.png);
    background-position: bottom;
    height: 75px;
}
#FooterBottom {
    background: url(../images/FooterBottomBottom.png) repeat
}
#FooterLeft, #FooterRight {
    position: absolute
}
#FooterLeft {
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 485px;
    margin: 15px;
    left: 0;
}
#FooterLeft h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
}
.FooterFeatureImage, .FooterFeatureCopy {
    display: inline
}
.FooterFeatureCopy {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 600px;
    text-align: left;
}
.FooterFeatureCopy p {
    width: 250px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.FooterFeatureImage {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
.white {
    color: #fff
}
.shadow {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #555;
}
.Background_white {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    padding: 3px 8px;
    width: 150px;
}
.top_15 {
    margin-top: 150px
}
.Now {
    background: url(../images/footer/now.jpg) no-repeat
}
.WireWorks {
    background: url(../images/footer/WireWorks_Footer.jpg) repeat
}
.GinAndJuice {
    background: url(../images/footer/Apparel.jpg) no-repeat
}
.BreweryTour {
    background: url(../images/footer/BreweryTour_Footer.jpg) no-repeat
}
.MedfordRum {
    background: url(../images/footer/MedfordRum_Footer.jpg) repeat
}
.Firepuncher {
    background: url(../images/footer/Firepuncher_Footer.jpg) repeat
}
.AboutBack {
    background: url(../images/About_Footer.jpg) no-repeat
}
.WireWorksMartini {
    background: url(../images/footer/WireWorksMartini_Footer.jpg) no-repeat
}
.HankyPanky {
    background: url(../images/footer/HankyPanky_Footer.jpg) no-repeat
}
#FooterRight {
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(../images/Menu_Back.jpg);
}
#FooterRight p {
    line-height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
#FooterRight h1 {
    margin-top: 40px
}
.D_inline {
    display: inline
}
.right {
    float: right
}
#twitter_div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 220px;
    overflow: visible;
    border: 1px solid #221b5e;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 12px;
}
.TwitterFont {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff;
}
.TwitterFont a {
    color: #be6045
}
.Facebook iframe {
    border: none;
    height: 60px;
}
.Distilled {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 340px;
    padding: 40px 20px 0 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.Distilled2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 340px;
    padding: 40px 20px 0 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.DistilledMed {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 550px;
    padding: 40px 20px 0 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.DistilledBig {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 650px;
    padding: 40px 20px 0 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.DistilledBig p {
    padding-right: 20px;
    line-height: 150%;
    text-align: justify;
}
.Distilled h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #231f20;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.Distilled2 h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #231f20;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.Distilled2 h3 {
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}
.DistilledMed h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #ae1414;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.DistilledMed h3 {
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: justify;
}
.Distilled p {
    padding-right: 20px;
    line-height: 150%;
    text-align: justify;
}
.Distilled2 p {
    padding-right: 20px;
    line-height: 150%;
    text-align: justify;
}
.DistilledMed p {
    padding-right: 20px;
    line-height: 150%;
    text-align: left;
}
.FooterFeatureCopy h1 {
    line-height: 50px
}
.Photos {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 640px;
    padding: 40px 20px 0 0;
    vertical-align: top;
}












.dropdowns{float:left;width:690px;padding:0 0 10px;border-bottom:2px solid #d7d3c6}
.dropdowns a{float:left;width:190px;padding:5px 12px;color:#000;, georgia, serif;font-size:16px;background:#cdc1ab url("/assets/global/dropdown-bg.png") 190px 8px no-repeat;line-height:16px;text-decoration:none;margin-right:10px}

.pagination{margin-top:1em;clear:both}.pagination span{float:left;display:block;margin-right:5px}.pagination .page{padding-top:2px}.pagination a{color:#706B61;text-decoration:none}.pagination .current,.pagination a:hover{color:#386388;text-decoration:underline}.pagination .first,.pagination .last{display:none}.pagination .prev a,.pagination .next a{display:block;text-indent:-9999em;overflow:hidden;width:22px;height:22px;float:left}.pagination .prev a{background:url(/assets/pagination-left.gif) no-repeat}.pagination .next a{background:url(/assets/pagination-right.gif) no-repeat}.sitemap-col{float:left;width:250px}.sitemap-content ul{list-style:none}.navWrap{z-index:1000}



.flexslider .flex-control-nav{position:fixed;left:40px;bottom:20px;text-align:left;width:auto}
.flexslider .non_sticky{position:absolute; bottom:40px}
.flexslider .flex-control-nav li{margin-left:7px}
.flexslider .flex-control-nav li a{width:10px;height:9px;background:url("../images/footer-carousel-nav.png") 0 -9px no-repeat; }
.flexslider .flex-control-nav li a:hover,.flexslider .flex-control-nav li a.active{background-position:0 0}

.flexOverlay{height:120px;width:500px;position:absolute;top:200px;left:75px;}
.flexOverlay p{margin-top:0; color:#fff; padding:20px; width:280px; background:rgba(35, 31, 32, .8); }
.flexOverlay h1 {font-size:55px; line-height:50px; text-shadow:1px 1px 4px #333; margin:0; color:#f0f0f0;}
.flexOverlay h1 a{color:rgba(235, 205, 200,.9); font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif; text-transform:uppercase; }
.flexOverlay h1 a:hover{color:rgba(190, 96, 69, .9)}



.flex-container a:active,.flexslider a:active{outline:none}
.slides,.flex-control-nav,.flex-direction-nav{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none}
.flexslider{width:100%;margin:0;padding:0}
.flexslider .slides > li{display:none}
.flexslider .slides img{max-width:100%; min-height:550px; display:block}
.flex-pauseplay span{text-transform:capitalize}
.slides:after{content:".";display:block;clear:both;visibility:hidden;line-height:0;height:0}
html[xmlns] .slides{display:block}
* html .slides{height:1%}
.no-js .slides > li:first-child{display:block}
.flexslider{position:relative;border-bottom:0;zoom:1}
.flexslider .slides{zoom:1}
.flexslider .slides > li{position:relative}
.flex-container{zoom:1;position:relative}
.flex-caption{background:none; zoom:1}
.flex-caption{width:96%; padding:2%; position:absolute; left:0;bottom:0;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);color:#fff;text-shadow:0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);font-size:14px; line-height:18px}
.flex-direction-nav li a{width:52px;height:52px;margin:-13px 0 0;display:block;background:url(/assets/flexslider/theme/bg_direction_nav.png) no-repeat 0 0;position:absolute;top:50%;cursor:pointer;text-indent:-9999px}
.flex-direction-nav li .next{background-position:-52px 0;right:-21px}
.flex-direction-nav li .prev{left:-20px}
.flex-direction-nav li .disabled{opacity:.3;filter:alpha(opacity=30);cursor:default}
.flex-control-nav{width:100%;position:absolute;bottom:-30px;text-align:center}
.flex-control-nav li{margin:0 0 0 5px;display:inline-block;zoom:1;*display:inline}
.flex-control-nav li:first-child{margin:0}
.flex-control-nav li a{width:13px;height:13px;display:block;background:url(/assets/flexslider/theme/bg_control_nav.png) no-repeat 0 0;cursor:pointer;text-indent:-9999px}.flex-control-nav li a:hover{background-position:0 -13px}
.flex-control-nav li a.active{background-position:0 -26px;cursor:default}

a{text-decoration:none; font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif; text-transform:uppercase}
p{color:#181818; line-height:30px; }
ul, li, ul li {text-align:left}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about which elements (list of all concerned class/id/el) cause problems? In IE7 the layout was indeed totally messed up, but it worked half-okay in IE8? NB: text-shadow isn't supported until IE 10, box-shadow until IE9. Rgb colors on backgrounds only work when they're set for the `background` property (not bg-color).. Can't provide a full answer, but hope this can help.

Comment: Welcome to the old IE. You are going to have to create a seperate css stylesheet for IE. Then use IE's conditional statements to call this stylesheet. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: IE8 and below don't support css3, so rgba backgrounds won't work but there are workarounds such as http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/ so you probably want to fall back to a solid background colour in the header. Also text-shadow and box-shadow aren't supported so you'll either need to go old school with some images or just cope without shadows for those (or overlay two blocks of text offset by 1px in x and y with the front one white and the back one black).

Comment: I fixed all of the backgrounds with the rgb trick. It is amazing how terrible IE seems to be. There are still issues to fix, but thank you so much for getting me on track.

Answer (score -1):

IE doesn't support %, or has great difficulty in doing so. Change you code to px a